# 'Unknown exception' when editing vector layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, vector-layer

I keep coming across the unknown exception error message when trying to edit or add to a vector layer. Anyone else come across this problem? Any fixes? I'm currently running QGIS 3.4

[image]

Comment: Can you please *edit* your question and add some details about the data you are trying to edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Export and save the layer which you want to edit in a different name of course. Now try to edit.

Comment: Same problem occurs even with the new layer.